# Find a farm's database server and instance in PowerShell

Tags: development, powershell, sql-server

How can I find the SQL server name AND instance where my databases are stored using PowerShell?  Assuming I am not using an alias and can't check cliconfg.

In servers in farm, I can see the server name but no the instance. I have the same issue if I run

```
Get-SPServer  | select name
```

If I select any of the other properties (role, serviceinstances, etc.) only the name gets displayed.

Another close one was the cmdlet Get-SPDatabase with parameter -ServerInstance.. but I have to know the server instance.

I found this block of C# code, but I'm not sure how to run it. Can someone explain how I can run the [C# code to get instance name](http://rajeshsharepointtechie.blogspot.com/2012/09/to-find-out-sql-server-instance-name.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use the commandlet `Get-SPDatabase` there are several properties of the returned object that can give you the information you need.

```
$db = (Get-SPDatabase)[0]
$db.Server
```

Will print out the full server name, and I would assume instance, for that database. Another interesting property would be

```
$db.DatabaseConnectionString
```

That will print out something like

```
Data Source=SP2013;Initial Catalog=SP2013_State_Service_DB;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15
```

Data Source will contain the full server and instance name as well. I'll convert that code for you and add it as an edit.

Here is the code on the link you gave converted to PoSh. I have not wrapped it in a function as I am not sure how you might want to use it...

```
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
}
Start-SPAssignment -Global

    $farm = Get-SPFarm

    foreach ($server in $farm.Servers)
    {
        foreach ($svc in $server.ServiceInstances)
        {
            if($svc -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabaseServiceInstance])
            {
                $s = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabaseServiceInstance]$svc;
                if([System.string]::IsNullOrEmpty($s.Instance))
                {
                    $svc.DisplayName
                }
                else
                { 
                    $svc.DispalyName + "\" + $s.Instance
                }
            }

        }
    }


Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

Comment: This is great.  Both do the job.  I find that you don't need this in the script    `code`$sp = Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"`code`

Comment: In mean time I was writing the same script with pipes :). Copy-Paste this in SharePoint Management Shell: Get-SPFarm | foreach { $_.Servers | ForEach-Object { $a = $_; $_.ServiceInstances | foreach { if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceInstance]$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDatabaseServiceInstance]) { Write-Host $a; Write-Host $_.DisplayName }}}}

Comment: Awesome, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, the .DatabaseConnectionString got me the correct info (SQLInstance name) where .Server only returns the SQLServer. +1'd